# A question of minimising the expression.

Tags: triangles, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, geometric-inequalities

Let $P$ be any point inside $\Delta ABC$ whose distance from $\overline{BC}, \overline{AC}, \overline{AB}$ (or $a$, $b$ and $c$) be respectively $x$, $y$ and $z$. Then minimum value of $\frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{y} + \frac{c}{z}$ is ?

Comment: What are a,b,c?

Comment: try Cauchy Schwarz

Comment: @neonpokharkar sides of the triangle

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner suggest something that's known for a 16 year old -.-   ^.^

Comment: ok, this is an former IMO problem

Comment: Do you know triangle trignometrics

Comment: @neonpokharkar I guess yes

Comment: What does "Let $P$ be a point whose distance from $a$ is $x$" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By C-S
$$(ax+by+cz)\left(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z}\right)\geq(a+b+c)^2$$
Thus, $$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z}\geq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2S_{\Delta ABC}}.$$
The equality occurs for $$(ax+by+cz)||\left(\frac{a}{x},\frac{b}{y},\frac{c}{z}\right),$$
which says that $\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{2S_{\Delta ABC}}$ is a minimal value.

The inequality 
$$(ax+by+cz)\left(\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}+\frac{c}{z}\right)\geq(a+b+c)^2$$ we can proof without C-S of course, but it's very ugly:

We need to prove that
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+\frac{abx}{y}+\frac{aby}{x}+\frac{acx}{z}+\frac{acz}{x}+\frac{bcy}{z}+\frac{bcz}{y}\geq$$
$$\geq a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2ac+2bc$$ or
$$ab\left(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}-2\right)+ac\left(\frac{x}{z}+\frac{z}{x}-2\right)+bc\left(\frac{y}{z}+\frac{z}{y}-2\right)\geq0$$ or
$$\frac{ab(x-y)^2}{xy}+\frac{ac(x-z)^2}{xz}+\frac{bc(y-z)^2}{yz}\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Comment: Anything else other than C-S?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

prove that $$A=\frac{1}{2}(xa+yb+zc)$$ where $A$ is the area of the given triangle

Comment: How? And after that? A detailed solution would be helpful